# How to remove directory from .zip

Tags: c#, directory

I want to delete a folder inside a .zip file.

I tried with

```
zip.RemoveEntry(META-INF);
```

but it not work

How do I delete?

I´m using IonicZip

Answer (score 0):

You have to use quotation marks, because `RemoveEntry` expects the filename and you probably didn't define `META-INF`.

You will have to change your code to this:

```
zip.RemoveEntry("META-INF");
```